# Java + Postgresql : How to store Parent and List of all children in a HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, hashmap

I have an sql table Children :

```
| ParentName | ChildrenName |
 ———————————————————————————
| parent 1   | child 1      |
| parent 1   | child 2      |
| parent 2   | child 3      |
| parent 1   | child 4      |
| ...        | ....         |
```

My goal is to construct a java `HashMap<String , ArrayList<String>>` that contains ParentName as key and a list of `ChildrenName` as value.

Should I perform the processing by using an sql query? Or select all data and process it via java?

Comment: Write a simple query, execute it via JDBC and create the `Map<String, List<String>>` from the `ResultSet` if you can't / mustn't use frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concerning your second option:

Get all data from the database with a simple query and map the data in Java**

You can do it like this (read the code comments):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide a query as String
    String query = "SELECT ParentName, ChildName FROM some_table";
    // provide the data structure
    Map<String, List<String>> results = new HashMap<>();
    // connect to your database
    Connection connection; // this has to be created using a suitable JDBC implementation

    try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String parentName = rs.getString(1);
            String childName = rs.getString(2);

            // add them to the map
            if (results.containsKey(parentName)) {
                /* 
                 * if the key already exists in the map, 
                 * just add the current name to its value(s)
                 */
                results.get(parentName).add(childName);
            } else {
                // create a new list as the value for the new key
                List<String> childNames = new ArrayList<>();
                // add the current child name to it
                childNames.add(childName);
                // and put the new key and value in the map
                results.put(parentName, childNames);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // print the results
    results.forEach((p, c) -> System.out.println(p + ": " + String.join(", ", c)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Following this approach I managed to create the HashMap I needed. It seems that it is also efficient since .containsKey and .get Method have O(1) time complexity right?

Comment: @leo.nanos The efficiency should be ok, but might be optimizable. Optimize your query, too, in order to achieve optimal efficiency. Glad this helped you...

Answer (score 1):

So, in the end you always need to create the objects (if you are not using JPA mapping). Therefore there is not a real "do it in java or sql" difference here.
You should also be aware of how much data you are selecting, you can easily reach the memory limit of your laptop or server.

I would suggest you select pages of data from the database and transform them in your needed object structure.

The select would something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM parent, child WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id ORDER BY parent.id LIMIT 0, 100
```

You would then have to write Java code with loops over the returned results and only stops, if there are no more results returned.

If you need more, then please ask. You are very vague with your question on how the result should look like. (Do you need for SQL or Java Code? Do you need help with the general algorithm? How much data do we speak of?)

Comment: 1) I am pretty sure that I wont have memory issues, as the input is a result of  UI elements selection by click. (wont reach even 100 in most cases). 2) I am trying to find out if it is more efficient to write a simple query and transform data using java loops, or using a more accurate query to bring data back formed as I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jdbc, example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example", "postgres", "postgres")) {

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM public.parentAndChildrens");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("parent is: " + resultSet.getString("ParentName") + "childrenis: " + resultSet.getString("ChildrenName"));
        }    
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection failure.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And than you can fill your map.

Comment: I use java.sql package to handle database operations. I cant use JPA. I am trying to achieve this using only sql statements and java manipulation.